# checking conditions of string index

Tags: python, if-statement

am having trouble checking the conditions over the string index

```
string = '1234'
```

I have two conditions as below

```
Conditions : 3rd and 4th position should be  34, or 2nd position should be 2
```

code :

```
if x[2] =='3' and x[3] == '4' or x[1] == '2' : 
     print('correct')
else:
     print('wrong')
```

here, am not able to understand how does it satisfy the condition. 3rd and 4th together could be written separably as in the above code.

Please suggest

Comment: I don't understand your question. The code prints 'correct', and all conditions are satisfied. Other than that, `x[2] =='3' and x[3] == '4'` can be written as `x[2:4] == '34'`

Comment: how about this one,
if x[-2:] =='34' or x[1] == '2' :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`and` operator has higher precedence than `or` operator. So it's equivalent to:

```
if (x[2] =='3' and x[3] == '4') or (x[1] == '2') : 
     print('correct')
else:
     print('wrong')
```